# Difference between feature branch and long term branch in GitHub GUI?

Tags: git, github

The project I am working on has three main long-term branches which are master, release, and develop. Generally it follows the gitflow workflow.

I want to make a feature branch off of develop. When I create the feature branch through the GitHub GUI it shows up like other branches.

Is there a way to have this feature branch off develop show up differently so it is clear that it is a feature branch rather than one of the three long-term branches (master, release, develop)?

Comment: I'm not sure if Github GUI does this, but some Git GUIs group your branches when using slashes. I.e: ``features/feature-name`` which is cool.

Comment: As far as Git (or GitHub, for that matter) is concerned they're all just branches. "Feature branches" and "long-term branches" don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch is a branch, no more no less.

There is no way to show some diffrently than others.

The only solution is to communicate between developers contributing to the project adopting a convention like 'feature/my_branch_that_add_a_feature'.

Then 'feature' is now sort of a folder (and is managed by git exactly like that) where you will put only your feature branches.

And that's how git flow works....